# How to get correct length of string in motd?

Tags: bash, string-length

I'm new to bash script. I made my original motd script on my server machine(ubuntu 20.04). In that script, I'm trying to get a length of string. It works correctly on server machine. However it displayed wrong number, when I connected to server machine from laptop(OSX 11.1 and ubuntu 20.04) by using ssh. Could you tell me why it is happening?

```
</etc/update-motd.d/my-motd>

#!/bin/bash
line1="██╗"
printf "${#line1}"
```

It will return 9 but it should 3...
Also, this problem only happens at ssh login.

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, there is a Unicode character. According to POSIX, shell should have Unicode support, but it must be switched on with a proper variable(s).

Therefore either the machine you call "laptop" or the account you connect to is not configured to have a locale with utf-8 support. Try to set at least `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` but setting to your proper locale (and maybe even LANG or LC_ALL) variables would be even better.

For details on so called internatinalisation variables, please see: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html (TL;DR: LANG makes a default for unset vars, LC_ allows some granularity, LC_ALL is the boss.)

Comment: @d.c.Thank you for your answer. This is my first post and I did not expect to get an answer so soon. I was able to solve the problem by adding "LANG=en_US.utf8" to the script.